# Bayesian parameter estimation: Transforming parameters to use uninformed priors

Tags: bayesian, parameterization, back-transformation

First of all: Please excuse my ignorance. There are some parts of the concept of bayesian inference I may have not yet understand!

What I have so far: I have count data with a negativ binomial distribution and I want to fit a model to this data. The model contains of two unknown parameters (**b** and **n**).

**b** is real-valued on an interval between 0 and 1 and should be normal distributed. **n** is also real-valued and normal distributed (on an invinit scale), too.
I want to estimate these parameter values.

Here I give you my R code to run with rjags:

```
model {
 for (i in 1:N) {

  y[i] ~ dnegbin (p[i], r)  

  p[i] <- r / (r + mu[i])  
  mu[i] <- b * n * (1 - exp(-x[i] / n)) 

  }

  r ~ dunif(0, 500)  
  logit(b) <- logit.b

logit.b ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)  
  log(n) <- log.n

  log.n ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)  

 }
```

I decided to use a logistic transformation on parameter **b** and a logaritmic transformation for parameter **n**, with a correspondent normal distribution.

**My Questions**

1. When I use the proposed code, the posterior distribution is for the transformed parameters. Any further examination with the resulting mcmc.list object will give me these transformed values. Is there a possibility to back transform the results **inside** the mcmc.list object or before they are stored as such?
2. The more fundamental question: Is this transformation a correct procedure after all, or should I use a proper distribution for the prior in the first place? In that case, what distribution would you propose?

Comment: Can you post the R code you use to run the inference?

Comment: Regarding your title: uninformative priors have nothing to do with transforming your data, you do not need to make any transformations to use them. However you do not relate to the title in your question so it is hard to comment anything more since it is unclear what you are doing and why.

Comment: @Tim you are correct. My title is not the best. But I am aware of what you pointed out about uninformed priors. I did NOT transformed my data, but used a transformation for the parameter b and n which are unknown. my data is denoted as y and x in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are free to transform any parameter prior to MCMC sampling in a Bayesian analysis. If you want them later in other units, just transform them back - there is no dedicated function for that for coda::mcmc, but internally a coda::mcmc object is just a matrix, just apply your backtransformation on the parameters and that's that.
2. If you transform the parameters, you also have to transform your prior accordingly, so that the amount of prior probability mapped on each area of the parameter space stays constant. Hence, a transformation has no bearing on the prior choice - it is mostly applied to make MCMCs sample more efficiently.
3. Regarding how to choose priors - the literature and CV is full of text on that. I would maybe start with the classic Kass, R. E. & Wasserman, L. (1996) The selection of prior distributions by formal rules. J. Am. Stat. Assoc., 91, 1343-1370.